# Calling java native method from Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, java-native-interface, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb-java

I am trying to create an instance of a rocksDB cache from Kotlin.

```
val cache = org.rocksdb.LRUCache(500L * 1024L * 1024L)
```

But I am getting an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'long org.rocksdb.LRUCache.newLRUCache(long, int, boolean, double)'
    at org.rocksdb.LRUCache.newLRUCache(Native Method)
    at org.rocksdb.LRUCache.<init>(LRUCache.java:74)
    at org.rocksdb.LRUCache.<init>(LRUCache.java:19)
    at application.CustomRocksDbConfigSetter.<clinit>(RocksDb.kt:41)
    at application.RocksDbKt.configureRocksDb(RocksDb.kt:15)
    at application.StreamsStarter.configureProperties(StreamsStarter.kt:30)
    at application.StreamsStarter.execute(StreamsStarter.kt:19)
    at main.ModulesKt.mainModule(Modules.kt:18)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method.callMethod(CallerImpl.kt:97)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.calls.CallerImpl$Method$Static.call(CallerImpl.kt:106)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.call(KCallableImpl.kt:108)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.callDefaultMethod$kotlin_reflection(KCallableImpl.kt:159)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KCallableImpl.callBy(KCallableImpl.kt:112)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.internal.CallableUtilsKt.callFunctionWithInjection(CallableUtils.kt:119)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.internal.CallableUtilsKt.executeModuleFunction(CallableUtils.kt:36)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$launchModuleByName$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:331)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$launchModuleByName$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:330)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.avoidingDoubleStartupFor(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:355)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.launchModuleByName(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:330)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.access$launchModuleByName(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:32)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$instantiateAndConfigureApplication$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:311)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading$instantiateAndConfigureApplication$1.invoke(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:309)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.avoidingDoubleStartup(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:337)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.instantiateAndConfigureApplication(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:309)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.createApplication(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:150)
    at io.ktor.server.engine.ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.start(ApplicationEngineEnvironmentReloading.kt:276)
    at io.ktor.server.netty.NettyApplicationEngine.start(NettyApplicationEngine.kt:212)
    at io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(EngineMain.kt:32)
```

I see the cache internal code and it invokes this function:

```
private native static long newLRUCache(final long capacity,
      final int numShardBits, final boolean strictCapacityLimit,
      final double highPriPoolRatio);
```

Is this not supposed to work when invoked from Kotlin?

Comment: Kotlin isn’t the source of the problem. It seems you haven’t linked your compiled code library. If it’s part of a dependency, you might have neglected some initialization step you’re supposed to do that would internally load native libraries.

Comment: Indeed. I have to start Kafka Streams first. Thank you .